# Calculating PCA of a dataset using both matlab and R but getting different variances per component

Tags: r, matlab, machine-learning, bigdata, pca

I am trying to visualize a 5 featured dataset using PCA. I am using both matlab and R. In R i use the prcomp() command and in matlab I use the pca() command. Both uses SVD to gain the principal components but i get a huge difference in variance in each of the principal components between matlab and R. In matlab, i receive a 95 % variance in the first component and 3 % in the second while in R the first component has around 42 percentage variance and around 28 % on the second. How come they varies this much?

I can also mention that I am planning to later use the data for a machine learning model and would like to use the principal components to reduce the dimensionality. Should i use the result from matlab or R?

Sidenote: I am displaying the variance per component in R using fviz_eig().

Edit:

The R code:

```
res.pca <- prcomp(dataset, scale=TRUE)
fviz_eig(res.pca)
```

Matlab code:

```
[coeff, score,~,~,var, mean] = pca(dataset,'algorithm','SVD');
bar(var)
```

The "dataset" is a csv file with 5 features and each feature contains 257493 observations.

Comment: As you are not showing code, there is one possibility: you are doing it wrong. We can not prove or disprove this claim

Comment: Edit the question with code and a dataset using the output of `dput(data)` or, if the dataset is too big, `dput(head(data, 30))`, please.

Comment: What parameters do you use? For example, do you specify to centre and scale the data in both cases? As others have said, you need to provide data and code.

Comment: I don't think you need PCA for 5 dimensions. Most classifiers should be able to handle them just fine.

Comment: I have inserted the code now. I know that most classifiers can handle 5 features but this work is for a thesis and therefore i need to make a comparison with pca and without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @Lyngbakr in the comment the probable reason fir the observed discrepancy is the fact that you specified the variables to be scaled in the R code and not in the matlab code.

Here is an example within R:

Generate variables with different magnitudes (random uniform noise with different magnitudes):

```
x1 <- runif(100, 200, 500)
x2 <- runif(100, 20, 50)
x3 <- runif(100, 2, 5)
x4 <- runif(100, 0.2, 0.5)

mat <- cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

do PCA without scaling:

```
pca1 <- prcomp(mat)
pca1$sdev
[1] 80.27564312  8.15330049  0.82751057  0.08491903
```

The standard deviations reflect the different ranges of the variables

If you only center the variables, leave the variances as they are, this is often called "PCA based on covariances":

```
cov(mat)
            x1           x2         x3           x4
x1 6444.144562 11.149336032 9.70055864 -1.191862833
x2   11.149336 66.495763487 0.06598063 -0.001822713
x3    9.700559  0.065980626 0.69928547  0.007559200
x4   -1.191863 -0.001822713 0.00755920  0.007560817
```

If you also standardize the variables to variances = 1, this is often called "PCA based on correlations".

```
pca2 <- prcomp(mat, scale = TRUE)
pca2$sdev
[1] 1.1308637 1.0205627 0.9624318 0.8679425
```

When the data is scaled the standard deviations of the principal components tell a different story.

```
cov(scale(mat))

            x1           x2          x3           x4
x1  1.00000000  0.017032146 0.144506324 -0.170749431
x2  0.01703215  1.000000000 0.009675918 -0.002570615
x3  0.14450632  0.009675918 1.000000000  0.103959503
x4 -0.17074943 -0.002570615 0.103959503  1.000000000

all.equal(cov(scale(mat)), cor(mat))
[1] TRUE
```

An image says a thousand words:

```
library(ggbiplot)
library(cowplot)

plot_grid(ggbiplot(pca1),
          ggbiplot(pca2),
          labels = c("not scaled", "scaled"))
```

[image]

The `prcomp` with scaling should be similar to `Weighted PCA` in `matlab` where the inverse variable variances are used as weights while performing the principal components analysis.

```
[coeff,~,latent,~,explained] = pca(dataset,...'VariableWeights','variance')
```

I do not have matlab to test.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried prcomp() without scaling and received the same results as in matlab. I see that a lot of people use scale in R when making their PCA. Why is it necessary?

Comment: @Adnan Hossain glad to help. Check out these two answers about scaling: [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110508/questions-on-pca-when-are-pcs-independent-why-is-pca-sensitive-to-scaling-why) and [two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-data-before-principal-component-analysis-pca).